# Android / Eclipse trouble with applying themes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I'm new to Android and seem to be hung up a bit...

I am trying to build my first Android App. The App is mostly just the template Eclipse creates for you...

I would like to use a base of the Holo Theme and with a default black background. I can get it to work (on the simulator) by hard coding "@android:style/Theme.Holo" in the Manifest. But I can't get it to pull that out of the styles.xml.

Even if I do hard code it in the Manifest, Eclipse still shows a white background in the Activity editor which makes designing with white text on a white background difficult...

I'm sure it's something small I am missing. Please see below...

Thanks in advance
Peter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.domain.test2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon48"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="ca.domain.test2.Something"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're putting it in res/values/styles.xml file, which means it's being applied to an app for every API version, but versions up to 10 don't support Holo themes. So, this is how your files should look like:

*res/values/styles.xml*

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular 
         API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

*res/values-v11/styles.xml*

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

*res/values-v14/styles.xml*

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: That worked. I knew it was getting overwritten somewhere. I was thinking of the inheritance backwards. Thanks.